# Where can i find ELSETS with Co-Variances?

Tags: debris, two-line-elements, sensors

For Special Permutations (I'm a novice), an ELSET with covariance is more accurate than without covariance.  A TLE doesn't have room for any covariance.  However, I can't seem to find a catalog that provides this.  In CCSDS's OEM, the 3x3 or 6x6 covariance is optional.  I've looked at Gunter's, Johathan's (mostly), space-track and esa.int but no covariance.  Does anybody know of a publicly accessible catalog that has this information?

Comment: The CCSDS OEM is fairly new. It's from this millennium, which makes it fairly new by aerospace standards. While spacecraft move quickly, the aerospace community does not. We deal with hardware from the previous millennium, compilers from the previous decade (and sometimes, from the previous millennium), software designs from the previous millennium, etc.

Comment: The problem with covariance is it says *how good* tracking is.  It is calculated from sensor performance, sensor locations, and measurement schedule, which some fear could give away sensitive information about military collection systems.  The details of *what* is known are often less sensitive than *how* it is known.

Comment: Yes, I work with VCM (Vector Covariance Messages).  Space Force is moving towards CCSDS, mainly for the public-accessible catalog.  The NASA Horizon Ephemerides site uses TLEs for planetary orbit determination, so the Special Perturbations and the Covariance isn't included.

Comment: As a Scenario - The military sensors network releases the ephemerides generated from their sensors including Covariance along with Special Perturbations to be used with commercial set of Ephemerides  to determine Time of Closest Approach (TCA).  The question - can one reverse-engineer the ephemerides so they can determine the Covariance?